# What can I use to view a mobile device remotely instead of VNC options which are too slow?

Tags: user-interface, testing, mobile, vnc, mirroring

We have a dozen or so mobile devices for testing. Emulators in SDK's like Android's or Xcode have quirks. So, we use actually devices.

I've tried browser synchronization like browser-sync but that routes everything through a proxy.

I'm looking for a way to remotely view and control these devices from a desktop. I've tried running a VNC server on the mobile devices, but VNC is just too slow. Not to mention, the devices themselves lack any real processing power.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try seeTest Manual tool http://experitest.com/support-2/seetest-pricing-manual/. It is a free tool. Very easy to install and setup.
You can remotely connect and control your android and iphone devices from PC. It is just like interacting with the mobile phone from desktop.